# How to add backdropClass for mat-select?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

```
<mat-select formControlName="country" panelClass="CountySelect" backdropClass="full-width"></mat-select>
```

Want to add `backdropClass` to specific mat-select `cdk-overlay-pane`. How can we do it. No input called `backdropClass` for mat-select in the documentation. Can this be done? Or any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried panelClass

Comment: Yes, But panelClass is different. I want to add class to `cdk-overlay`.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appBackdropClass]'
})
export class PanelClassDirective implements DoCheck {
  @Input('appBackdropClass') panelClass: string;

  constructor(private _host: MatSelect) {
  }

  ngDoCheck(): void {
    if (this._host.overlayDir) {
      this._host.overlayDir.hasBackdrop = true;
      this._host.overlayDir.backdropClass = this.panelClass;
    }
  }
}
```

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select appBackdropClass="test">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not use directive because of `Property 'overlayDir' does not exist on type 'MatSelec` error. Thus, I used `ViewChild` property decorator to set custom class to backdrop.

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   @ViewChild(MatSelect, {static: false})
   selectComponent;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.selectComponent.overlayDir.backdropClick.subscribe(evt => console.log(evt));
     this.selectComponent.overlayDir.backdropClass = "yourClassName";
   }

}
```

and in the template:

```
  <mat-select disableOptionCentering panelClass="panel-class-name" overlayDir>
    <mat-option>
      value 1
    </mat-option>
    ....
    
  </mat-select>
```